# on a project TabListener cannot be resolved but working on another project with no error

Tags: android

I am working on a project trying to create actionbartab ...
and I am facing error `TabListener cannot be resolved to a type`
what is **weird** I added the same code in another project and it worked , I was able to compile it and run it.

 But in my project I am not able to compile it,I am having TabListener cannot be resolved.  I added the same import and used the same code.

the below is my code with the import:

```
public class Display extends ActionBarActivity {
    private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grid_main);
         //have to use getSupportActionBar from android.support.v7.app
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
      //hello tab
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.ta)
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<HelloFragment>(this, "hello", HelloFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        //handle content tab
        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.snd)
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<HandleContentFragment>(this, "handle", HandleContentFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        //getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            // Send intent to SingleViewActivity
       Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleViewActivity.class);
       // Pass image index
       i.putExtra("id", position);
       startActivity(i);
       } });

        }
```

Comment: Took a look at the ActionBar.TabListener source code, apparently it's not a generic class, it's actually an interface, are you using the same TabListener in both projects from the same package? [ActionBar.TabListener](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/ActionBar.java)

Comment: @JorgeMendez yes the same package called example , and I am following up the link You gave

Comment: @JorgeMendez from site you gave where should I put the code ?

Comment: It's not a sample code, it's the ActionBar's source code. As I can see, you're not using the native TabListener interface, you're using one from a custom library probably. Make sure you have that dependency added to the second project

Comment: @JorgeMendez I get the above code from a tutorial , I didnt understand how to use the actionbar source code ? and do you know a good tutorial where I can apply actionbar ? the android developer site wasent that helpful as they didn't provide much details

Comment: Did you follow this tutorial? [Adding ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) if that wasn't helpful enough, you can take a look at this one [ActionBar Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

Comment: @JorgeMendez I followed up Vogella tutorial and I had errors .. I posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206240/error-why-working-contextual-action-mode-start-actionmodeis-not-applicable-for-t 

 can you have a look ?